# CakePHP 2 accessing variable defined in the view

Tags: php, cakephp, migration, cakephp-2.0

In both [cakephp-1.2](/questions/tagged/cakephp-1.2) and [cakephp-1.3](/questions/tagged/cakephp-1.3) I have used the following code snippet in an element named `head` called from the `blog` layout:

```
$this->preMetaValues = array(
    'title' => __('SiteTitle', true).' '.$title_for_layout,
    'desc' => Configure::read('siteTitle').', '.Configure::read('siteSlogan'),
    'keywords' => Configure::read('keywords'),
    'type' => 'article',
    'site_name' => __('SiteTitle', true),
    'imageURL' => $html->url('/img/logo.png', true)
);
if(!isset($this->metaValues)){
  $this->metaValues = $this->preMetaValues;
}
else{
  $this->metaValues = array_merge($this->preMetaValues, $this->metaValues);
}

<?php echo $html->meta('description',$this->metaValues['desc']); ?>
<?php echo $html->meta('keywords', $this->metaValues['keywords']);?>
```

I used the above code to define or modify meta-tags values from the any view file. The `preMetaValues` is regarded as the default values. If there is any `metaValues` defined in the view, this code will modify it and make the `metaValues` ready to be used.

**Now** with [cakephp-2.4](/questions/tagged/cakephp-2.4), the described code generates the following error:

> **Helper class metaValuesHelper could not be found.**
>
> Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.

Indeed, I don't know why CakePHP regards this variable as helper? and how could I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by setting the variable from your controller action:

```
$this->set('title_for_layout', 'Your title');
```

And then in the view, printing it with:

```
<title><?php echo $title_for_layout?></title>
```

You have an example of this at the documentation:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#layouts

Just treat them as any other variable.

Comment: I don't think that an option! I meant by the idea itself. Why it considered this as a Helper? and How could I overcome it within the view?

Comment: Why is not an option? Why don't you just set the variable from the controller?

Comment: Because I don't want to take care about it in every controller's action. In other words, the default values defined in `preMetaValues` will be printed either I regarded `metaValues` or not. If follow what you are suggested, It may generate undefined variable error if it is not defined in every controller's action using this layout!

Comment: You have two options then. Remove the `$this->` and treat them as normal `php` variables inside your view/layout. (`$preMetaValues`, ...) or set them in the `onBeforeFilter` of your `AppController.php`.

Comment: Additionaly, the logic I use, will make separation between the programming logic and SEO tasks. In other words, the SEO specialist could only take care with view as designer.

Comment: Then try my last answer, treat them as normal variables, delete the `$this->`

Comment: There is a problem, in CakePHP 2.4 it seems that it process the layout before processing the view, so when I set $metaValues in the view it does not recognized as defined!

Comment: Can you post any link to that problem? It seems very weird having a such a big bug in a CakePHP version.

Answer (score 0):

Why you're using $this object? Can't you use a simple solution like this:

```
$preMetaValues = array(
    'title' => __('SiteTitle', true).' '.$title_for_layout,
    'desc' => Configure::read('siteTitle').', '.Configure::read('siteSlogan'),
    'keywords' => Configure::read('keywords'),
    'type' => 'article',
    'site_name' => __('SiteTitle', true),
    'imageURL' => $html->url('/img/logo.png', true)
);
if(!isset($metaValues)){
  $metaValues = $preMetaValues;
}
else{
  $metaValues = array_merge($preMetaValues, $metaValues);
}

<?php echo $html->meta('description',$metaValues['desc']); ?>
<?php echo $html->meta('keywords', $metaValues['keywords']);?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found the solution. It is simply about how to set a variable for the layout from a view. It seems that in earlier versions of [cakephp](/questions/tagged/cakephp) the view was processed before the layout while now in [cakephp-2.4](/questions/tagged/cakephp-2.4) the layout is processed first, so any override of any variable defined in the layout from the view will not success.

Hence, the solution will depend on the [**set** method of the view object](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-View.html#_set) something as follows:

```
//in some view such as index.ctp
    $this->set('metaValues', array(
                                   'title', 'The title string...',
                                   'desc' => 'The description string...'
                                   )
              );
```

Also as [Alvaro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1081396/alvaro) regarded in his answer, I have to access those variable without $this, i.e as local variables.

This answer is inspired from: [Pass a variable from view to layout in CakePHP - or where else to put this logic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411560/pass-a-variable-from-view-to-layout-in-cakephp-or-where-else-to-put-this-logic)